# Ringtone and contact tone not set Programatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-activity

i m making an app in which i m download ringtones from server and save in sdcard/download and set as alarm,Notification,ringtone and contact tone but when i set it  does not set as contact and ringtone but notification,alarm tone set where is mistake in my code secondly through /sdcard/download/ tones is not save in ome mobile  while through /Download/

```
    ringtone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/" + title;
                        setRingtone(path);
                        Toast.makeText(con, "set successfully as ringtone"+title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                alaram.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/" + title;
                        setalaram(path);
                        Toast.makeText(con, "set successfully as alaram", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/" + title;
                        setnotication(path);
                        Toast.makeText(con, "set successfully as notification", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
               /* contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/" + title;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });*/

            }
        });
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                    urlRingTone = String.valueOf(data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI));
                    break;
                case 2:
                        Uri contactData = data.getData();
                        Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/" + title;
                            //setContact(path);
                        }

            }

        }
public void setalaram(String path) {


        File k = new File(path); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, title);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Play.this,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
    }

    public void setnotication(String path) {


        File k = new File(path); // path is a file to /sdcard/media/ringtone

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, title);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, k.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Play.this,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, for a ringtone must use :  `RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE`

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
  Play.this,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
  newUri
);
```

and

```
 values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
```

Check this complete example:

```
File k = new File(path, "Queen-BohemianRhapsody.mp3"); 

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Bohemian Rhapsody");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 188080);
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Queen");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 230);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newUri = this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(myActivity,
  RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,  newUri);
```

Comment: thanks for response  so i have already use this code in our app but no one set as ringtone and contact tone!!

Comment: when i set custom ringtone as a ringtone when a call is incoming ringtone not ringing